# I need to create an App which insert data from PDF forms to SQL base

Tags: c#, sql, excel, powershell, pdf

I need to create a background app like a 'job' that runs everyday in a specific directory. This job have to pick up a bunch of PDF forms that have been filled (all those forms are purchase orders) and extract then insert those data into a purchase orders Microsoft SQL database.

I know that Excel as a pretty good import feature for this situation but I need it to be automatic and more like a "Service" which really runs in background.
I've been looking for ideas on how to approach the problem and I did not find much so, if you guys have any ideas I would love to hear about them.

Edit : I think a good solution would be a powershell script which does it all, loop, import, insert.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I kinda see what you mean but for me to extract at a specific hour I already need to create some kind of script so,why wouldn't I just do everything from there ?

Comment: I'll take a look a that thank you for those precisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a C# Console Application for that. Write a console app that extracts data from Excel/PDF then writes it directly to MsSQL database. Then trigger it with Scheduled Tasks on windows.

Comment: Yes that's what I think I would go for, however I don't know yet if C# is the best compared to powershell here?

Comment: I used C# for a similar operation. It has been a very practical and trouble-free solution for me. I preferred it because I use C# a lot to read data from the file and print it to the database. @UneJoliefleur

Comment: Yes, I ended up starting a C# console app thank you !